# Why is the animation not playing when I click on the button?I have created an animation in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to animate the boxes by clicking on the start button, but when I click on the start button, the boxes don't move. What is wrong?
Here is the github:
https://github.com/Garima5/negativeWorkDone/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Any error messages in console?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="info">
        <form>
            <button type="submit" id="animate" onclick="animate()">Start</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Leave it as

```
<div id="info">
    <button id="animate">Start</button>
</div>
```

and then in the code of your script, for example, right before the `animate()` function put this:

```
document.getElementById("animate").addEventListener("click", animate, false);
```